# Does this formalism adequately describe functions of one variable?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $f$ be a function mapping every element of a set $X$ to a unique element denoted by $f(x)$ in a set $Y$.

Can this statement be effectively formalized by

> $\forall a (a\in X \implies f(a) \in Y)$

What logical aspects of functionality, if any, would not be captured by this statement.

Comment: Do you just mean that $f$ is well-defined (not one-to-many), or that $f$ is a constant function, that is, all elements of $X$ map to the same unique element of $Y$?

Comment: Seems like you're missing the uniqueness of $f(a)$ given $a$.

Comment: @Randall It is trivial to show that $\forall a (a\in X \implies f(a)=f(a))$

Comment: Why is that?  Why can't I have two different $f(a)$'s, each one making your implication true?

Comment: @Randall If $f(a)=b$ and $f(a)=c$, by substitution have $b=c$. Thus $f(a)$ can have only a single value.

Comment: But that assumes already that $f(a)$ is well-defined.  Anyway, I'm stopping.

Comment: I think that you are conflating *function symbols* of FOL, with *functions* of set theory (formalized in FOL). Set theory has **no** "primitive" function symbols and functions are sets, i.e. "objects" of the domain. Thus, the "basic" formalization is $(a,b) \in f$ and we have **to prove** functionality. After that, we can introduce the abbreviation $(a,f(a))$.

Comment: Regarding the language of set theory, see e.g. Patrick Suppes, [Axiomatic set theory (1960)](https://books.google.it/books?id=sxr4LrgJGeAC&pg=PA24), page 24-25 : the author proves the Theorem : Theorem 11. $(\exists ! C)(\forall x)(x \in C \leftrightarrow (x \in A \land x \in B))$ **and then** "The theorem just proved formally justifies the definition of intersection" and the author introduces a new *function symbol* : $A \cap B$.

Comment: Regarding *functions* as sets, see [page 86](https://books.google.it/books?id=sxr4LrgJGeAC&pg=PA86); having defined *relations* (=sets of *pairs*) the author defines : "$f$ is a function iff $f$ is a relation and $(\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z)( xfy \land xfz \to y = z)$."

Answer (score 5):

For a more or less standard FOL, as is typically used to formalize, e.g., ZFC set theory, writing $f(a)$ already implies that $f$ is a function. Your statement would merely add that the image of $X$ is contained in $Y$. If that's all you want, then this is fine.

Fixing $a\in X$, if $f$ is a set-theoretic function, as opposed to a logical function symbol, then $f(a)\in Y$ would mean something like $\exists y\in Y.(a,y)\in f$. This would imply $f$ is a total relation on $X$, but not that it is functional which would just add that such a $y$ has to be unique. This is the point of Randall's comments. Without the uniqueness constraint, $f$ could readily be a relation that relates $a$ to multiple elements of $Y$. Your argument that you can "trivially" show $f(a)=f(a)$ doesn't work when $f$ is not a function symbol. *There is no term $f(a)$ in this context.*<sup>1</sup> Instead $f(x)=y$ is interpreted as $(x,y)\in f$, so in your case you'd get $f(a)=f(a)$ means $(a,f(a))\in f$ means $\exists b.(a,b)\in f\land(a,b)\in f$ which is, of course, equivalent to just $\exists b.(a,b)\in f$ which in no way states that that $b$ is unique.

$f$ may still not be a function since we haven't said anything about how it behaves outside of $X$. You can add an additional constraint: $\forall a,b.(a,b)\in f\implies a\in X$ which would say that $f$ is only "defined" on $X$. In APC89's answer, this is accomplished by requiring $f\subset X\times Y$.

If you just want to specify that a binary relation $f$ is a function $X$ to $Y$, then APC89's answer provides the more or less standard definition for this, except for the unnecessary insistence that $X$ and $Y$ be non-empty. (Of course, if $Y$ is empty and $X$ is non-empty, there won't actually *be* any functions from $X$ to $Y$. On the other hand, $X$ being empty causes no problems at all.)

<sup>1</sup> If your logic has a definite description quantifier, you could say it is the term $\iota b.(a,b)\in f$, but this also would require $f$ to separately be shown to be a functional relation for this to give a useful result.

Answer (score 3):

Given two non-empty sets $A$ and $B$, we say that the binary relation $f\subset A\times B$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ if and only if
\begin{align*}
(\forall a\in A)(\exists!b\in B)\quad\text{such that}\quad(a,b)\in f
\end{align*}

Comment: I am familiar with the that particular formalism.Could you comment on the one I presented here?

Comment: I guess the heading wasn't very clear. I have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

If the symbols $f$, $X$, and $Y$ are established to be interpreted so that $f$ is a function and $X,Y$ are sets, then your formalism captures $X\subseteq \mathrm{dom}(f)$ and $\mathrm{ran}(f\big|_X)\subseteq Y$. It does not establish that $f$ is a function and $X,Y$ are sets---that must be established before writing the formalism.

Comment: What aspect of functionality is not captured by my formalism? Uniqueness is built into the notation. From f(x)=a and f(x)=b, we can infer by substitution that a=b.